# How to package spring-boot as multiple JARs with launcher?

Tags: spring-boot

I am trying to reduce my Docker layer sizes (not the overall image) by copying smaller chunks of data into the container.  This will hopefully prevent the tls timeout which I cannot change on Azure DevOps.

However, spring-boot normally packages everything as a single uber JAR.  I was wondering if it was possible to have spring-boot repackage it such that it is multiple JARs.

The other bonus of this is if I can COPY the spring-boot and dependency JAR files first they may be able to reuse the layer in another image.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem. I even had to split lib folder so I write own maven plugin. You can use it if you use maven for building and you want. [sb-aplitter-plugin](https://github.com/antonsjava/sb-splitter-plugin)